# Stop dropdown from closing with click inside (CSS only)

Tags: html, css

Can I stop my dropdown from closing when I click inside it? I can't click any of the results because it closes the menu. Thanks!
I'm talking about the search bar, when I click the searchbar to type something, the dropdown opens, the problem is, if I try clicking the anchors inside of it, or anywhere inside of it, the dropdown closes! How do I make it NOT close when I click inside? Can I solve this with HTML/CSS only? Thanks!

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #27272B;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.dropdown-title-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  border: solid black 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
  padding-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 290px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdowna {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}

.div {
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0vw 0vw 1vw black;
  margin: 1.5vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  padding-top: 0vw;
  padding-bottom: 0vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

#trocarvariaveis {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

footer {
  margin-left: 2px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f0db4f;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.headerdiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.backtotop {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.backtotoptext {
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.55em;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: -30px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: black;
}

.backtotop:hover .backtotoptext {
  color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}

.backtotop:hover .material-symbols-outlined {
  color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}

.githubcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.githublink {
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.githublink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.searchbarcontainer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 125px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.searchbarinput {
  height: 32px;
  width: 225px;
  font-size: 1.225em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
}

.searchbarinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.serchbarbutton {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-left: none;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 600, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48
}

.searchbarbuttonicon {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-self: center;
}

.searchbardropdown {
  display: none;
}

.searchbarinput:focus~.searchbardropdown {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 141px;
  width: 267px;
  background-color: #F6F7EB;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="javascriptlogo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,700,0,0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
  <title>Javascript Exercicios</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="myheader" class="sticky">
    <div class="headerdiv">
      <div class="backtotop">
        <a class="material-symbols-outlined" href="#">arrow_upward</a>
        <a class="backtotoptext" href="#">Voltar ao topo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="githubcontainer">
        <a href="https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios" target="_blank" class="githublink">//GITHUB LINK</a>
      </div>
      <div class="searchbarcontainer">
        <script src="searchbar.js"></script>
        <div class="searchbar">
        </div><input class="searchbarinput" id="searchbarinput" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar.."><button class="serchbarbutton" type="submit"><i class="material-symbols-outlined searchbarbuttonicon">search</i></button>
        <ul class="searchbardropdown">
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#">Trocar Variaveis<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis">Celsius para Farenheit<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit">Farenheit para Celsius<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius">Area Circulo<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">Par ou Impar<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">Intervalo entre numeros<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo">Intervalo dentro de vetor<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor">Maior e menor numero<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor">Paisagem ou retrato<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato">Fizz ou Buzz<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">String do objeto<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject">Par ou impar ate limite<br></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-title-container">
          <p class="dropdown-title">MENU</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#">// Trocar Variaveis<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis">// Celsius para Farenheit<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit">// Farenheit para Celsius<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius">// Area Circulo<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">// Par ou Impar<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">// Intervalo entre numeros<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo">// Intervalo dentro de vetor<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor">// Maior e menor numero<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor">// Paisagem ou retrato<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato">// Fizz ou Buzz<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">// String do objeto<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject">// Par ou impar ate limite<br></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the searchbar is showing up on the wrong place because I havent added responsiveness yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just managed to figure it out!
**Adding a :hover to my dropbox solved the issue!** The problem was, the moment I clicked outsid my input, it stop being :focus, so even if the click was inside the dropdown, the input stop being on :focus and so the dropdown went back to being hidden. Adding a :hover to the dropdown made that clicking the input and making it :focus activates de dropdown and then simply hovering it would keep it open!

Here is the updated CSS code:

```
    display: none;
  }
  .searchbarinput:focus ~ .searchbardropdown{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 141px;
    width: 267px;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
  .searchbardropdown:hover{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 141px;
    width: 267px;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
```